# Cleaning up after multiple docker inserts

Tags: docker

I do multiple inserts, threaded one after the other:

```
$ docker insert ubuntu http://google.com /tmp/test1
IMG1
$ docker insert IMG1 http://google.com /tmp/test2
IMG2
$ docker insert IMG2 http://google.com /tmp/test3
IMG3
```

Now, I delete `IMG3`:

```
$ docker rmi IMG3
Deleted IMG1
Deleted IMG2
Deleted IMG3
```

If I run the sequence again, to get images `IMG1'`, `IMG2'`, `IMG3'` then removing `IMG3'` fails

```
$ docker rmi IMG3'
Error: no such id: IMG2
```

Notice it's `IMG2`, wihtout the prime. If I reboot, the sequence works again, only once.

What am I doing wrong? How can I delete all images related to a sequence of inserts?

Comment: I tried that and it works for me. I have not encountered your problem.  Is it possible that this issue related to some docker version?

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Which version are you using? It fails for me on a fresh checkout from master.

Comment: hmm, i can't reproduce it after pulling from master today :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know solution for your problem, but I use graphviz output format of docker images to debug issues related to images. It helps me a lot to visualize relations:

```
docker images -a -viz
```

You can visualize the output online in this app (copy & paste the output):

http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/